# obtaining rotated table from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table, called `T726`, that contains data like the example below (The example is the result of a `Select * from T726`):

```
id      |   regvalue  |   timest
-----------------------------------
id16    |   541       | 1510141964
id17    |   80        | 1510141964
id700   |   17012547  | 1510141964
id701   |   306045210 | 1510141964
id16    |   773       | 1510141975
id17    |   90        | 1510141975
id700   |   17012547  | 1510141975
id701   |   306045211 | 1510141975
id16    |   478       | 1510142008
id17    |   23        | 1510142008
id700   |   17012547  | 1510142008
id701   |   306045212 | 1510142008
id16    |   90        | 1510146939
id17    |   11        | 1510146939
id700   |   17013961  | 1510146939
id701   |   306045170 | 1510146939
```

On my SQL client (I am currently using `SQuirreL`), there is the option to get the result as rotated table, like the example below:

```
timestamp    |   id16   |   id17  |   id700     |   id701      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
1510141964   |   541    |   80    |   17012547  |   306045210  |
1510141975   |   773    |   90    |   17012547  |   306045211  |
1510142008   |   478    |   23    |   17012547  |   306045212  |
1510146939   |   90     |   11    |   17013961  |   306045170  |
```

I surfed the net and I found the there is a relational operation called [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx). However, I am not able to get that result using PIVOT in a select statement.

Any help is apreciated,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PIVOT

```
SELECT
*
FROM YourTable
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(regvalue)
        FOR
        Id IN
        (
            [id16],[id17],[id700],[id701]
        )
    )P
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use of simple conditional aggregation instead of `PIVOT` operator

```
select timest,
       max(case when id= 'id16' then regvalue end) [id16],
       ...
       max(case when id= 'id701' then regvalue end) [id701]
from table
group by timest
```

**EDIT :** Use `pivot` with dynamic style

```
declare @col varchar(max), @q varchar(max)

set @col = stuff(
                    (select  distinct ','+quotename(id) from #tm for xml path('')),
                 1,1,'')

set @q = 'select * from table
          PIVOT 
          (
            MAX(regvalue) FOR id IN ('+@col+')
          )p'

EXEC (@Q)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please find the solution.**

**Data GENERATION**

CREATE TABLE TstPivot
    (
         id VARCHAR(10)
        ,regvalue BIGINT
        ,timest BIGINT
    )
    GO

```
INSERT INTO TstPivot VALUES
('id16'    ,541       ,1510141964),
('id17'    ,80        ,1510141964),
('id700'   ,17012547  ,1510141964),
('id701'   ,306045210 ,1510141964),
('id16'    ,773       ,1510141975),
('id17'    ,90        ,1510141975),
('id700'   ,17012547  ,1510141975),
('id701'   ,306045211 ,1510141975),
('id16'   ,478       ,1510142008),
('id17'    ,23        ,1510142008),
('id700'   ,17012547  ,1510142008),
('id701'   ,306045212 ,1510142008),
('id16'    ,90        ,1510146939),
('id17'    ,11        ,1510146939),
('id700'   ,17013961  ,1510146939),
('id701'   ,306045170 ,1510146939)
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT * FROM TstPivot
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(regvalue) FOR id IN ([id16],[id17],[id700],[id701])
)m
```

**OUTPUT**

```
timest               id16                 id17                 id700                id701
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1510141964           541                  80                   17012547             306045210
1510141975           773                  90                   17012547             306045211
1510142008           478                  23                   17012547             306045212
1510146939           90                   11                   17013961             306045170

(4 rows affected)
```